# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1210 Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

the following code is giving me this error on a shared host where there is no value to the viewed table in db

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM viewed WHERE memberID = :memberID";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $total = $stmt->fetchColumn();    

$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM viewed WHERE memberID = :memberID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :per_page OFFSET :offset";

         $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bindParam(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

but on my config file is i remove

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

then the error disappears but without PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION how am i to know the errors?

thanks

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: you can. placeholders can take the place of any VALUES in the query. they can't take the place of keywords/descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you dont need to bind variables in the limit and offset. You should only use to bind in the where condition.You can put directly to query. See below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM viewed WHERE memberID = :memberID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $per_page OFFSET $offset";

         $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10' at line 1'

Comment: This is happening because you are using negative values(-10) in LIMIT or OFFSET command. Use only positive values.

Comment: The first error isn't due to binding the limit, you should never pass the value directly into the sql statement unless you computed this value directly. The original error is actually due to a negative value being passed into limit, just do a check on $per_page and make sure it isn't negative.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but I believe the problem is that you're using ":memberID" in the bindParam call. The parameter name is "memberID".

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM viewed WHERE memberID = :memberID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $per_page OFFSET $offset";

     $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
     $stmt->bindParam('memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: It will work either way in PDO. Originally it *required* the leading colon when you bind the parameter, then in later versions, it became optional.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10' at line 1'

Comment: when i remove the line setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  from my connection then those error dont show up

Comment: @BillKarwin TIL :-)